# s3 retrieve all delete marker versions from s3 bucket prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

when i run this query

```
    aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket bucket_name --prefix assets/x.jpg --query 'DeleteMarkers[?IsLatest==`true` && LastModified>=`2021-10-1T08:00:00` && LastModified<=`2021-11-31T08:00:00`].[Key, VersionId]'
```

it returns successfully x object key and versionid from folder assets, but i want to get all files that has deleted in this assets folder in specific date so when i run

```
    aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket bucket_name --prefix assets/ --query 'DeleteMarkers[?IsLatest==`true` && LastModified>=`2021-10-1T08:00:00` && LastModified<=`2021-11-31T08:00:00`].[Key, VersionId]'
```

with removing x.jpg file which i mean by that to get all files in assets folder but last command is not worknig cause it take too much to execute then send me message in terminal display "killed process" message

Comment: How many objects are in your bucket?

Comment: This prefix contain Millions of objects @John

Comment: Ah -- There we have the issue! With that many objects, attempting to list the objects, or the object versions, would take a long time and would likely exhaust memory. I recommend that you use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects and their versions.